# Creating a tracker using php java-script and html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a tracker using php java-script and html. I need to check all records date and highlight(color) all cell having date less than 30 days from current date.
Right now I am fetching the data by below code

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from vendor";
$conn = Database::connect ();
$stmt = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
$result = $stmt->execute ();
if ($result) {
foreach ( $stmt->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_FUNC, 'feat_product' ) as $row ) {
}
}
?>

function feat_product($bgserial, $claimexpiry, $expirydate, $projectcode, 
$vendorname, $ponumber, $currency, $inhouse, $guarantee, $division, 
$issuedate, $bgtype) {

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $bgserial . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $claimexpiry . '</td>';

echo '<td>' . $expirydate . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $vendorname . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $projectcode . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $ponumber . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $currency . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $inhouse . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $guarantee . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $division . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $issuedate . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $bgtype . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

}

Comment: Are you working on product section where you need to check upcoming expiry ? Same thing I did for one of my clients where I create three reports - expiry in 1 month , expiry in 2 months and expiry in 3 months . Check my answer which will solve your problem .

Comment: Yes i need to check the expiry date of bank document . Please let me know your ans

Answer (score 0):

I'm submitting a code , just put the variable names according to your variables :-

```
$today = date("d-m-Y") ;
$exp = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($exp_date));
$expDate =  date_create($exp);
$todayDate = date_create($today);
$diff = date_diff($todayDate, $expDate);
if ($diff->format("%R%a") < 30){
    //Your code here
}
```